# How Can I Get width and height of "video-stream html5-main-video"?

Tags: html, jquery, video, height, width

I Have a Sample Code Here

```
<video tabindex="-1" 
    class="video-stream html5-main-video" 
    webkit-playsinline="" 
    playsinline="" 
    controlslist="nodownload" 
    style="width: 129px; 
    height: 230px; 
    left: 139.312px; 
    top: 0px;" 
    src="blob:the youtube url"></video>
```

at this code, I want get height and width. but when i use source like this

```
var videoSize = $('video-stream html5-main-video').css('width') +","+ $('video-stream html5-main-video').css('height'); 
videoSize.replace(/px/g, "");
```

it say 'undefined' How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `$('video-stream html5-main-video')` is not a valid selector. Given that you're selecting by multiple classes on the same element it should be `$('.video-stream.html5-main-video')`. Voting to close this question as a typo

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm sorry when i used $('.video-stream.html5-main-video') it also say undefined,undefined T.T